# How to apply cart price rules for new customers in a customer group immediately after they are added?

Tags: sales-order, shopping-cart-price-rules, customer-group

When a customer is added to  customer group, the customer group's cart price rules for new customer are only applied after the customer has completed their first order. How can I override this behavior?

Comment: Which type of cart price rule you are creating?

Comment: Any type of rule that is applicable to the customer group will not be applied to the customer until they make the first order after added to the customer group.